# Who can be a mahram for hajj?

Tags: women, hajj, mahram

Can a person who is my paternal cousin (my father's sister's son), who has married to my younger sister, also the person is elder to me, be a mahram for me to perform hajj?

I understand the person will be a mahram for my younger sister as he is her husband.

Will he be a mahram for me if I travel along with them?

Answer (score 3):

**No, the husband of your younger sister couldn't be Mahram to you even if he is your father's sister's son.** (Even if you travel along with them. (as far as I know). Then you ought to observe your Islamic code in front of him.

It could be beneficial for you to read the verse below (in regard to the persons who are Mahram to women):

> وَقُل لِّلْمُؤْمِنَاتِ يَغْضُضْنَ مِنْ أَبْصَارِهِنَّ وَيَحْفَظْنَ
>   فُرُوجَهُنَّ وَلَا يُبْدِينَ زِينَتَهُنَّ إِلَّا مَا ظَهَرَ مِنْهَا ۖ
>   وَلْيَضْرِبْنَ بِخُمُرِهِنَّ عَلَىٰ جُيُوبِهِنَّ ۖ وَلَا يُبْدِينَ
>   زِينَتَهُنَّ إِلَّا لِبُعُولَتِهِنَّ أَوْ آبَائِهِنَّ أَوْ آبَاءِ
>   بُعُولَتِهِنَّ أَوْ أَبْنَائِهِنَّ أَوْ أَبْنَاءِ بُعُولَتِهِنَّ أَوْ
>   إِخْوَانِهِنَّ أَوْ بَنِي إِخْوَانِهِنَّ أَوْ بَنِي أَخَوَاتِهِنَّ
>   أَوْ نِسَائِهِنَّ أَوْ مَا مَلَكَتْ أَيْمَانُهُنَّ أَوِ التَّابِعِينَ
>   غَيْرِ أُولِي الْإِرْبَةِ مِنَ الرِّجَالِ أَوِ الطِّفْلِ الَّذِينَ
>   لَمْ يَظْهَرُوا عَلَىٰ عَوْرَاتِ النِّسَاءِ ۖ وَلَا يَضْرِبْنَ
>   بِأَرْجُلِهِنَّ لِيُعْلَمَ مَا يُخْفِينَ مِن زِينَتِهِنَّ ۚ وَتُوبُوا
>   إِلَى اللَّـهِ جَمِيعًا أَيُّهَ الْمُؤْمِنُونَ لَعَلَّكُمْ تُفْلِحُونَ
>   ﴿٣١﴾
>
> And tell the believing women to reduce [some] of their vision and
>   guard their private parts and not expose their adornment except that
>   which [necessarily] appears thereof and to wrap [a portion of] their
>   headcovers over their chests and not expose their adornment except to
>   their husbands, their fathers, their husbands' fathers, their sons,
>   their husbands' sons, their brothers, their brothers' sons, their
>   sisters' sons, their women, that which their right hands possess, or
>   those male attendants having no physical desire, or children who are
>   not yet aware of the private aspects of women. And let them not stamp
>   their feet to make known what they conceal of their adornment. And
>   turn to Allah in repentance, all of you, O believers, that you might
>   succeed. (31)
>
> (Noor:31)

---

**Reference(s):**

- [http://tanzil.net](http://tanzil.net/#trans/en.sahih/24:31)
- [www.hawzah.net](http://www.hawzah.net/fa/Question/View/63706/)

Comment: How can you be sure about it?? Is there a hadith that says about mahram? Please quote it. It might be helpful for her and the people who look at this post in future.

Comment: Other than husbands, their fathers, their husbands' fathers, their sons, their husbands' sons, their brothers, their brothers' sons, their sisters' sons, all are non Mehrams. All people NOT included under Mehrams are non Mehrams.